# Error when making a post request with json data containing backslash's to notion-api

Tags: python, json, notion-api

I'm trying to add a new entry to a notion database using a python code. For this, i'm querying the database and using the structure of an already existing entry as the template. The problem I'm facing is that one of the ids for the properties I'm trying to update contains two '\' :

```
"Worktype": { "id": "Z\\=g", "type": "select", "select": { "id": "_WG~", "name": "Firmware", "color": "orange" } }
```

I can successfully change the property name, but when i try to make the post request the notion API throws an error:

```
'{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"body '
                'failed validation. Fix one:\
               body.properties.Z\\\\=g.title should be '
                'defined, instead was `undefined`.\
```

It seems that the API is not capable to correctly parse the backslash.

I have already tried a lot of solutions for replacing the backslash, of for creating the JSON in diferent ways.

Comment: If it needs to have \\ and not just \ you will need to put \\\\. The '\' is an escape character in JSON. So, you need to properly escape the string.

Comment: Also, it appears that you are missing your first { in the JSON. Not sure if that was just a copy/paste mistake or if that is actually your JSON.

Comment: The problem is that i want to have the \\ but when sending to the API it reads \\\\ and throws an error.